# Davisson and Germer experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, electrons, wave-particle-duality

I was reading about the experiment that confirms the wave particle duality as we see a sudden rise in galvanometer which was explained as a phenomenon of constructive interference.

Is it possible that the galvanometer shows zero deflection even if electron reaches the collector plate i.e. a phenomenon of destructive interference ?

Or

Is it somehow possible to get destructive interference of the electrons in this experiment ?

**NOTE :** I went through the answers and now I want to ask you that is it possible to get complete destructive interference such that the galvanometer shows zero deflection ? What could be the experimental set-up for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, constructive interference is *always* paired with destructive interference; the overall amount of the particle has to stay the same, after all. The low points of the galvanometer reading correspond to destructive interference. Compare a classical scattering plot - for example, [edit: this particular] [Rutherford Scattering](https://images.app.goo.gl/a8kHVWTGvqUEphaCA) of alpha particles (Helium nuclei) off of atoms does not display any noticeable interference patterns[ or other effects]. [A plot](https://images.app.goo.gl/TUptMpGzJFrUkyvo6) from a Davisson and Germer experiment shows notable deviation from this classical scattering behavior[ in a manner that is predicted by quantum interference calculations].

In the first part of your question, the destructive interference *is* the decreased likelihood of the electron reaching the collector plate. The electrons are instead more preferentially going in the direction of constructive interference, so the plate placed at the destructive interference angles can not capture them.

**Response to question edit:**
If you perfectly canceled out the wavefunction at any point, then there would be perfect destructive interference there, which would only give your background galvanometer reading. How perfect destructive interference can be is limited by the details of the setup; setup geometry, beam quality, sample uniformity, temperature etc. could all reduce the degree of cancellation; I don't know about the exact details of the elements of a Davisson and Germer experiment well enough to say much more about this. Overall, if you want to see perfect destructive interference of electron beams, diffraction grating experiments like [this one](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1060&context=mrsecfacpubs) might be a better place to look.

Comment: Yet crystal channeling in RBS, where the incoming particles are channeled down crystal directions, is a thing. And, Lindhart used the fact that overall particles stay the same to get the channeling distributions. (But, this is not an interference effect, but a many-body effect).

Comment: Yes, I gave that as a classical example of what would be expected without any other effects, as a comparison to the D-G plot results to show what the quantum interference effect is. Sorry about the misstatement here.